# How can I show a page in chrome headless from Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, travis-ci

I'd like to use headless Chrome to run the autotest suite of the [Transcrypt](http://www.transcrypt.org) Python to JavaScript compiler on Travis.

But I haven't been able to find out how to start Chrome from Python.
Travis keeps trying using w3m and then tells me that it can't load the pages with testresuls.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My .travis.yml is:

```
dist: xenial
sudo: yes

addons:
    chrome: stable

language: python
python:
    - '3.7'

install: pip install mypy
script: bash ./transcrypt/development/continuous_integration/run.sh
```

File run.sh is:

```
# Make everything executable and the rest
chmod -R 777 .

# Start headless browser instance, Python's webbrowser.open will now refer to this instance
google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &

# Enable shipment_test.py to find run_python
export PATH=$PATH:./transcrypt

# Run the shipment test
python ./transcrypt/development/shipment/shipment_test.py
```

Shipment_test.py is:

```
...
...
...

transpileCommand = 'transcrypt' if commandArgs.inst else 'run_transcrypt'

shipDir = os.path.dirname (os.path.abspath (__file__)) .replace ('\\', '/')
appRootDir = '/'.join  (shipDir.split ('/')[ : -2])

def getAbsPath (relPath):
    return '{}/{}'.format (appRootDir, relPath)

def test (relSourcePrepath, run, extraSwitches, messagePrename = '', nodeJs = False, build = True):
    # Compute some slugs
    sourcePrepath = getAbsPath (relSourcePrepath)
    sourcePrepathSplit = relSourcePrepath.split ("/")

    relTargetDir = f'{"/".join (sourcePrepathSplit [:-1])}/__target__'
    targetDir = getAbsPath (relTargetDir)

    moduleName = sourcePrepathSplit [-1]
    targetPrepath = f'{targetDir}/{moduleName}'

    relMessagePrepath = f'{relTargetDir}/{messagePrename}'
    messagePrepath = getAbsPath (relMessagePrepath)

    # If there are relevant console messages of the compilation process,
    # like with the static typechecking tests, write them into a file that can be served for a visual check
    if not os.path.exists (targetDir):
        os.makedirs (targetDir) # Transcrypt will make targetDir too late, so it has to happen here
    redirect = f' > {messagePrepath}.out' if messagePrename else ''

    # Transit switches
    transitSwitches = ''
    if commandArgs.dextex:
        transitSwitches += '-de '

    buildSwitch = '-b ' if build else ''

    # Compile with Transcrypt
    os.system (f'{transpileCommand} {buildSwitch}-da -sf -de -m -n {transitSwitches}{extraSwitches}{sourcePrepath}{redirect}')

    # Run back to back in CPython
    if run:
        os.system (f'{transpileCommand} -sf -r {switches}{sourcePrepath}')

    # Apply rollup to obtain monolith, since node doesn't support named imports and exports
    if nodeJs:
        os.system (f'rollup {targetPrepath}.js --o {targetPrepath}.bundle.js --f cjs')

    openNewTab = 2
    if not commandArgs.blind:
        if nodeJs:
            os.system (f'start cmd /k node {targetPrepath}.bundle.js'.format (moduleName))
            time.sleep (5)
            webbrowser.open ('http://localhost:8000', new = openNewTab)
            # webbrowser.open ('http://localhost:8090', new = openNewTab)
        else:
            webbrowser.open (f'http://localhost:8000/{relSourcePrepath}.html', new = openNewTab)
            # webbrowser.open (f'http://localhost:8080/{relSourcePrepath}.html', new = openNewTab)

os.system ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

# Start a node http server in the Transcryp/transcrypt directory
if not commandArgs.blind:
    os.system (f'start python http-server')
    # os.system (f'start cmd /k http-server {appRootDir} -p8080 -c-1')   # -c-1 means 'Clear cache'

# Allow visual check of command line options
os.system (f'{transpileCommand} -h')

# Perform all tests
for switches in (('', '-f ') if commandArgs.fcall else ('',)):
    test ('development/automated_tests/hello/autotest', True, switches)

    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Travis log:

```
Transcrypt (TM) Python to JavaScript Small Sane Subset Transpiler Version 3.7.7
Copyright (C) Geatec Engineering. License: Apache 2.0
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/testlet1.js
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/testlet0.js
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/itertools.js
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/org.transcrypt.autotester.html.js
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/org.transcrypt.autotester.js
Saving target code in: /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/__target__/autotest.js
Ready
Transcrypt (TM) Python to JavaScript Small Sane Subset Transpiler Version 3.7.7
Copyright (C) Geatec Engineering. License: Apache 2.0
Generating /home/travis/build/QQuick/Transcrypt/transcrypt/development/automated_tests/hello/autotest.html
Ready
w3m: Can't load http://localhost:8000/development/automated_tests/hello/autotest.html.
w3m: Can't load http://localhost:8000/development/automated_tests/hello/autotest.html
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick:

File .travis.yml, in the root of the GitHub repo:

```
dist: xenial
sudo: yes

addons:
    chrome: stable
    apt:
        packages:
            - chromium-chromedriver

before_script:
  - ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver ~/bin/chromedriver

language: python
python:
    - '3.7'

script:
    - bash ./transcrypt/development/continuous_integration/run.sh
```

File run.sh:

```
# Install Python modules

pip install mypy
pip install selenium

# Show where we are and what's there

pwd
ls -a -l

# Make everything executable and the rest

chmod -R 777 .

# Enable shipment_test.py to find run_python

export PATH=$PATH:./transcrypt

# Run the shipment test

python ./transcrypt/development/shipment/shipment_test.py --unattended
```

File shipment_test.py:

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
import datetime
import webbrowser
import argparse
import time
import traceback
import selenium
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.options
import pathlib

# ======== Command args singleton

class CommandArgs:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser ()

        self.argParser.add_argument ('-de', '--dextex', help = "show extended exception reports", action = 'store_true')
        self.argParser.add_argument ('-f', '--fcall', help = 'test fast calls', action = 'store_true')

        self.argParser.add_argument ('-i', '--inst', help = 'installed version rather than new one', action = 'store_true')
        self.argParser.add_argument ('-b', '--blind', help = 'don\'t start browser', action = 'store_true')

        self.argParser.add_argument ('-u', '--unattended', help = 'unattended mode', action = 'store_true')

        self.__dict__.update (self.argParser.parse_args () .__dict__)

commandArgs = CommandArgs ()

# ========  Browser controller singleton

class BrowserController:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.options = selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options ()

        self.options.add_argument ('start-maximized') 

        if commandArgs.unattended:
            self.options.add_argument ('--headless')          # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
            self.options.add_argument ('--no-sandbox')        # Bypass OS security model
            self.options.add_argument ('--disable-gpu')       # Applicable to windows OS only
            self.options.add_argument ('disable-infobars')
            self.options.add_argument ('--disable-extensions')    

        self.webDriver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome (chrome_options = self.options)
        self.browserIsRunning = False

    def open (self, url):
        print (f'Browser controller is opening URL: {url}')

        if self.browserIsRunning:

            if commandArgs.unattended:

                # ---- Show in existing tab

                self.webDriver.execute_script (f'window.location.href = "{url}";') 
            else:

                # ---- Open new tab

                self.webDriver.execute_script (f'window.open ("{url}","_blank");') 
        else:

            # ---- Open browser and default tab

            self.webDriver.get (url)
            self.browserIsRunning = True  

        try:
            self.message = self.webDriver.find_element_by_id ('message')
            print (f'Back to back autotest, result: {self.message.text.upper ()}')
            if 'succeeded' in self.message.text:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            print ('No back to back autotest')
            return True

browserController = BrowserController ()

# ======== Preparations

relSourcePrepathsOfErrors = []

nodeServerUrl = 'http://localhost:8090'
pythonHttpServerUrl = 'http://localhost:8000'
transpileCommand = 'transcrypt' if commandArgs.inst else 'run_transcrypt'

shipDir = os.path.dirname (os.path.abspath (__file__)) .replace ('\\', '/')
appRootDir = '/'.join  (shipDir.split ('/')[ : -2])

print (f'\nApplication root directory: {appRootDir}\n')


def getAbsPath (relPath):
    return '{}/{}'.format (appRootDir, relPath)

os.system ('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

# ---- Start an http server in the Transcryp/transcrypt directory

if not commandArgs.blind:
    if commandArgs.unattended:
        os.system (f'python -m http.server --directory {appRootDir} &')
    else:
        os.system (f'start python -m http.server --directory {appRootDir}')

# ---- Allow visual check of all command line options

os.system (f'{transpileCommand} -h')

# ======== Individual test function

def test (relSourcePrepath, run, extraSwitches, messagePrename = '', nodeJs = False, build = True, pause = 0, needsAttention = False):
    if commandArgs.unattended and needsAttention:
        return  # This test shouldn't be done, since it can't run unattended

    print (f'\n\n******** BEGIN TEST {relSourcePrepath} ********\n')

    time.sleep (pause)

    # ---- Compute some slugs

    sourcePrepath = getAbsPath (relSourcePrepath)
    sourcePrepathSplit = relSourcePrepath.split ("/")

    relTargetDir = f'{"/".join (sourcePrepathSplit [:-1])}/__target__'
    targetDir = getAbsPath (relTargetDir)

    moduleName = sourcePrepathSplit [-1]
    targetPrepath = f'{targetDir}/{moduleName}'

    relMessagePrepath = f'{relTargetDir}/{messagePrename}'
    messagePrepath = getAbsPath (relMessagePrepath)

    # ---- If there are relevant console messages of the compilation process,
    #       like with the static typechecking tests, write them into a file that can be served for a visual check

    if not os.path.exists (targetDir):
        os.makedirs (targetDir) # Transcrypt will make targetDir too late, so it has to happen here
    redirect = f' > {messagePrepath}.out' if messagePrename else ''

    # ---- Default switches

    defaultSwitches = '-da -sf -de -m -n '
    if commandArgs.dextex:
        defaultSwitches += '-de '
    if build:
        defaultSwitches += '-b '

    # ---- Compile with Transcrypt

    os.system (f'{transpileCommand} {defaultSwitches}{extraSwitches}{sourcePrepath}{redirect}')

    # ---- Run with CPython to generate HTML file with back to back reference info

    if run:
        os.system (f'{transpileCommand} -r {defaultSwitches}{extraSwitches}{sourcePrepath}')

    # ---- Apply rollup to obtain monolith, since node doesn't support named imports and exports

    if nodeJs:
        os.system (f'rollup {targetPrepath}.js --o {targetPrepath}.bundle.js --f cjs')

    if not commandArgs.blind:
        if nodeJs:
            os.system (f'start cmd /k node {targetPrepath}.bundle.js'.format (moduleName))
            time.sleep (5)
            url = nodeServerUrl
        else:
            url = f'{pythonHttpServerUrl}/{relSourcePrepath}.html'

        success = browserController.open (url)

    if commandArgs.unattended and not success:
        relSourcePrepathsOfErrors.append (relSourcePrepath)

    print (f'\n******** END TEST {relSourcePrepath} ********\n\n')

# ======== Perform individual tests

for switches in (('', '-f ') if commandArgs.fcall else ('',)):
    test ('development/automated_tests/hello/autotest', True, switches)
    test ('development/automated_tests/transcrypt/autotest', True, switches + '-c -xr -xg ')
    test ('development/automated_tests/time/autotest', True, switches, needsAttention = True)
    test ('development/automated_tests/re/autotest', True, switches)

    test ('development/manual_tests/module_random/module_random', False, switches)
    test ('development/manual_tests/transcrypt_only/transcrypt_only', False, switches)
    test ('development/manual_tests/transcrypt_and_python_results_differ/results', False, switches)
    test ('development/manual_tests/static_types/static_types', False, switches + '-ds -dc ', messagePrename = 'static_types')
    test ('development/manual_tests/async_await/test', False, switches)

    test ('demos/nodejs_demo/nodejs_demo', False, switches, nodeJs = True)
    test ('demos/terminal_demo/terminal_demo', False, switches, needsAttention = True)  
    test ('demos/hello/hello', False, switches, needsAttention = False)
    test ('demos/jquery_demo/jquery_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/d3js_demo/d3js_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/ios_app/ios_app', False, switches)
    test ('demos/react_demo/react_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/riot_demo/riot_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/plotly_demo/plotly_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/three_demo/three_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/pong/pong', False, switches)
    test ('demos/pysteroids_demo/pysteroids', False, switches)

    test ('demos/turtle_demos/star', False, switches, pause = 2)
    test ('demos/turtle_demos/snowflake', False, switches, pause = 2)
    test ('demos/turtle_demos/mondrian', False, switches, pause = 2)
    test ('demos/turtle_demos/mandala', False, switches, pause = 2)

    test ('demos/cyclejs_demo/cyclejs_demo', False, switches)
    test ('demos/cyclejs_demo/cyclejs_http_demo', False, switches, build = False)
    test ('demos/cyclejs_demo/component_demos/isolated_bmi_slider/bmi', False, switches)
    test ('demos/cyclejs_demo/component_demos/labeled_slider/labeled_slider', False, switches)

    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_010_hello_world/hello_world', False, switches)
    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_020_assign/assign', False, switches)
    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_030_if_else_prompt/if_else_prompt', False, switches, needsAttention = True)
    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_035_if_else_event/if_else_event', False, switches, needsAttention = True)
    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_040_for_simple/for_simple', False, switches)
    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_042_for_nested/for_nested', False, switches)
    test ('tutorials/baseline/bl_045_while_simple/while_simple', False, switches, needsAttention = True)

    test ('tutorials/static_typing/static_typing', False, switches + '-c -ds ', messagePrename = 'static_typing')

    if relSourcePrepathsOfErrors:
        print ('\n\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n')
        for relSourcePrepathOfError in relSourcePrepathsOfErrors:
            print (f'SHIPMENT TEST ERROR: {relSourcePrepathOfError}')
        print ('\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n\n')

        print ('\nSHIPMENT TEST FAILED\n')
        sys.exit (1)

    else:

        # ---- Make docs, the resulting files are untracked

        if not commandArgs.unattended:
            origDir = os.getcwd ()
            sphinxDir = '/'.join ([appRootDir, 'docs/sphinx'])
            os.chdir (sphinxDir)
            os.system ('touch *.rst')
            os.system ('make html')
            os.chdir (origDir)

        # ---- Terminate

        print ('\nSHIPMENT TEST SUCCEEDED\n')
        sys.exit (0)
```